# Enabling ongoing d3 node animation triggered by mousedown/drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a node animation that's triggered on an event like mousedown or drag, but doesn't die when the existing mousedown/drag event ends.

For example, when the user is dragging a node I want the node stroke-width to transition back and forth between 2 values.  So on my ondrag event I call a function that triggers the animation - which works great after 1 drag event if I keep the mouse where it is, but is immediately reset after the second, third drag etc.

I suppose what I'm asking is more of a javascript question, but does anyone know if there's any way that I can say "while (drag/mousedown)" instead of having to trigger a new call every time (and in the process destroy the reference to the old active call that was handling the animation).

Even with mousedown I have the same problem - i.e. the animation works great on click/hold, but then when you move the mouse, you get a mousemove event which destroys the reference to the running animation function.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Could you not simply start an animation (or a function to animate on an interval) on `dragstart/mousedown` and stop it on `dragend/mouseup`?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v0dnh9za/) is a Fiddle showing what I mean.

Comment: Hi JSBob - thanks for the advice, but that's what I've been trying to do - I'm starting a function on mousedown, but it's killed the second I move the mouse (assuming mousemove overwrites the mousedown event and so I lose the reference to the function I kicked off).  Same thing with dragstart - as soon as I move (and get a "drag" event), the function I've kicked off is lost.

Comment: Thanks JSBob!  Just saw your fiddle and will go through it now - please disregard my comment for now!

Comment: Hi JSBob, thank you that worked perfectly - I realised after looking at your code that I was calling the function from within another timer (that was supposed to detect a node-hold for a second but was also terminating my animation).  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help! Something I'd also like to note is that in the `stopAnim` method I transitioned it back to the original settings, but it still works fine without this since this is already included in the interval function.